# Locking a project into portrait in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have just begun creating a new Xcode project, and noticed that how I normally remove the function to have the app in landscape; a tick box under device orientation within the general tab of the project; has disappeared.

Has this orientation setting moved elsewhere, or must I now code it to lock it into portrait only?

Also, I am working in objective-c.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on your project on the left menu, next uncheck Landscape mode in Device Orientation:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you're clicking on your target and not your project in the project and target list.

Comment: Thanks andlin, thats what i was doing wrong, I didn't realise that project and target list was a thing, and was on project.

Comment: Ethan, if this answered your question you should note that and up vote to give proper credit.